# Azure B2C Monitor SigninLogs: Sign Up/Register

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-monitoring, appinsights

We are using Azure B2C and Azure Monitor to track metrics and issues for our production environment.

Does the SigninLogs include signups? User will use the custom policy B2C_1A_SigninSignup but will choose "Sign up" instead of sign in and will create an account.
Does this event go to the SigninLogs as well? Will the errors be in the logs?

If not how can we track the signups and their outcomes using Azure Monitor or AppInsights in production mode?

Answer (score 0):

By default you will have sign up event registered in the logs as sign in activity. To have detailed logs it is recommended to add detailed logging in your custom policy steps. Here you can read more about adding events:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/analytics-with-application-insights?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#add-events

With this approach you can collect granular information what is happening. Errors will be also collected in the Log Analytics connected with Azure AD B2C.